# ASP.NET MVC4 handling POST by Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, entity-framework, authentication

I am working on a login/register system in ASP.NET MVC4 with Entity Framework 6.0 (code-first) and I am wondering how should I correctly handle POST-s.

My User model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Autokereskedes.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        //Saját Kulcs
        [Key]
        public int UserId { set; get; }

        //Külső kulcsok

        //Model hivatkozások
        public List<Reservation> Reservations { set; get; }

        //Egyedi elemek
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [StringLength(254)]
        [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
        public string Email { set; get; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(100,MinimumLength=4)]
        [Display(Name = "Jelszó")]
        public string Password { set; get; }

        public string Phone { set; get; }

        public Boolean Banned { set; get; }
        public string Country { set; get; }
        public string City { set; get; }
        public string Street { set; get; }
        public int? ZipCode { set; get; }
        public DateTime RegistrationDate { set; get; }
        public DateTime? LastLoginDate { set; get; }
        public DateTime? PasswordChangedDate { set; get; }


    }
}
```

And my LogIn function:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        if (IsUserDataValid(user.Email, user.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, user.???)
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

I want to set persistent cookie, based on a checkbox in a login form, but my User model doesn't have a `public Boolean StayLoggedIn;` property and I don't want this option to be stored on my database as well. How should I handle this?

My login form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Sikertelen belépés, ellenőrizze adataid!");

    <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Email)</div>
    <div class="input-control text">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Email, new { @placeholder = "Írja be az email címét"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Email)
        <button class="btn-clear"></button>
    </div>
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)</div>
    <div class="input-control password">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Password, new { @placeholder = "Írja be jelszavát" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
        <button class="btn-reveal"></button>
    </div>
    <label class="input-control checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="helper">Bejelentkezve marad</span>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Bejelentkezés" />
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must create another model for you login page:

```
class LogInModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }

    public bool StayLoggedIn { get; set; }
}
```

and create your view based on this model and in controller just retrieve this mode.

It isn't a good idea to use user model in login page.

Comment: I think I will just go with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a RegisterInputModel and a LoginInputModel as per the default Account Model classes that come in the default project templates